# atmosphere long-polling doesn't reconnect after connection loss

Tags: internet-explorer-8, websocket, long-polling, atmosphere

After server crash or intermittent network failure, Atmosphere web socket client is able to reconnect to the server and receive messages.   However, atmosphere long-polling client(IE8) fails to reconnect.

My app is a live event browser that subscribes to a topic and displays all application events. Chrome and Firefox are working great, but, unfortunately, we still need to support IE8, therefore consistent behavior between WebSocket and Long-Polling is crucial.  What am I missing here?  Is this an Atmosphere bug??

**HOW TO REPRODUCE**

1. download atmosphere-chat example v2.0.3
   http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.atmosphere.samples%7Catmosphere-chat%7C2.0.0%7Cwar
2. modify application.js to use long-polling and to reconnect forever with 5 seconds interval.

   transport: 'long-polling'
   reconnect: true,
   maxReconnectOnClose: Number.MAX_VALUE
3. start Tomcat server and start chat
4. stop Tomcat abruptly
5. start Tomcat
6. Open another browser and send some message.
7. Original browser wouldn't receive message.

**[Long Polling:  Not-Working]**

```
onOpen called with {"url":"http://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat","contentType":"application/json","logLevel":"debug","transport":"long-polling","trackMessageLength":true,"reconnect":true,"maxReconnectOnClose":1.7976931348623157e+308,"reconnectInterval":5000,"enableXDR":true,"fallbackTransport":"long-polling"} atmosphere.js:2801
onMessage called. {"message":"Chrome","author":"Chrome","time":1381083093440} atmosphere.js:2801
onMessage called. {"message":"Hello","author":"Chrome","time":1381083099605} atmosphere.js:2801
<< Server Crashed>>
POST http://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0cbdf60…sport=polling&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json&_=1381083105434  atmosphere.js:1750
_executeRequest atmosphere.js:1750
_pushAjaxMessage atmosphere.js:2197
_push atmosphere.js:2143
push atmosphere.js:2511
request.onClose application.js:111
_f atmosphere.js:2405
_invokeFunction atmosphere.js:2361
_invokeCallback atmosphere.js:2455
_invokeClose atmosphere.js:2417
_executeRequest.ajaxRequest.onabort atmosphere.js:1593
_clearState atmosphere.js:344
_executeRequest.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange atmosphere.js:1652
Unable to connect to http://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat atmosphere.js:2801
GET http://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0cbdf60…-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true&_=1381083099613  atmosphere.js:1750
_executeRequest atmosphere.js:1750
_reconnect atmosphere.js:1840
_executeRequest.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange atmosphere.js:1735
<< Never Retries>>
```

**[Web Socket:  Working ]**

```
Invoking executeWebSocket atmosphere.js:2801
Using URL: ws://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.3-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true atmosphere.js:2801
Websocket successfully opened atmosphere.js:2801
onOpen called with with {"url":"http://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat","contentType":"application/json","logLevel":"debug","transport":"websocket","trackMessageLength":true,"reconnect":true,"maxReconnectOnClose":1.7976931348623157e+308,"reconnectInterval":5000,"enableXDR":true,"fallbackTransport":"long-polling"} atmosphere.js:2801
onMessage called. {"message":"Chrome","author":"Chrome","time":1381082675245} atmosphere.js:2801
onMessage called. {"message":"hello","author":"Chrome","time":1381082685115} atmosphere.js:2801
<< server crashed>>
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. atmosphere.js:2296
Invoking executeWebSocket atmosphere.js:2801
Using URL: ws://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=3764cd2f-6338-4478-bf35-b9f5fa105c7e&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.3-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=1381082719622&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true atmosphere.js:2801
Invoking executeWebSocket atmosphere.js:2801
Using URL: ws://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=3764cd2f-6338-4478-bf35-b9f5fa105c7e&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.3-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=1381082726651&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true atmosphere.js:2801
Invoking executeWebSocket atmosphere.js:2801
Using URL: ws://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=3764cd2f-6338-4478-bf35-b9f5fa105c7e&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.3-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=1381082733654&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true atmosphere.js:2801
Invoking executeWebSocket atmosphere.js:2801
Using URL: ws://localhost:8080/atmosphere-chat/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=3764cd2f-6338-4478-bf35-b9f5fa105c7e&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.3-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=1381082740657&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true atmosphere.js:2801
<< server Restarted>>
Websocket successfully opened atmosphere.js:2801
onMessage called. {"message":"IE10","author":"IE10","time":1381082755699}
```

Thanks!

Comment: just tested and everything worked fine. Which version of IE 8 are you using? Also which server Let's continue the discussion [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/atmosphere-framework?pli=1) as this sound more like a config issue than a bug in Atmosphere. -- Jeanfrancois